# Why is version number 0.10.0 considered as older than 0.9.0 in setuptools_scm?

Tags: python, version-control, git-tag, setuptools-scm

I have a Python package that is going through frequent changes and it brought us to version `0.9.3` currently. My team is not confident to bump it to `1.0.0` yet.

The team agreed to version number `0.10.0` but why `setuptools_scm` seems to consider `0.10.0` to be earlier than `0.9.3`?

I tried tagging with `git tag` and check the list:

```
$ git tag 0.10.0

$ git tag --list
0.10.0
0.2.0
0.2.1
0.2.2
0.3.0
0.5.0
0.7.0
0.7.1
0.8.0
0.8.1
0.9.0
0.9.1
0.9.2
0.9.3
```

Was expecting `0.10.0` to be listed after `0.9.3`.

Comment: Note that this is just a sorting error.  As a tag, 0.10.0 does come after 0.9.3.  One is the list (0, 10, 0) and the other is the list (0, 9, 3), and (0, 10, 0) > (0, 9, 3).

Comment: I think `git tag --sort=version:refname` is what you want (ascending order).

Comment: @Guildenstern Can you make an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is an answer from @Guildenstern. I post it as the answer now because the original author did not do so. All credit goes to @Guildenstern.

For ascending order:

```
git tag --sort=version:refname
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably because sorting a list of strings like this:

```
print(sorted(['0.9.0', '0.10.0']))
```

will return this:

```
['0.10.0', '0.9.0']
```

since 1<9 (its not 10 as a number)